# using igraph for Graphml network

Tags: python, graph, networkx, igraph, cytoscape

I have exported a network from CytoScape in graphml and I want to implement network community detection algorithms on this network using igraph. But I cannot import this network into python using igraph. On the other hand, igraph supports gml graphs. I could not convert graphml format to gml as well. Is there any way to use igraph on this network?

Comment: The docs of igraph in python states that you should be able to read GraphML and xml with igraph, see here: https://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html#igraph-and-the-outside-world. Do you have got an error for the `Graph.Read_GraphML()` method?

Comment: No, Graph.Read_GraphML() does not work.

Comment: Which error do you retrieve, if you call `ReadGraphML`? Have you checked if your GraphML file is correct, maybe try to read the file with `networkx`? Maybe try a really simple file first